# Zeppelin won't start with SSL enabled

Tags: hadoop, ssl, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I'm using Ambari 2.4.0.1 with HDP 2.5 and trying to configure Zeppelin to use SSL.  When I set the zeppelin.ssl property to "true" I always get this error when starting the server:

```
ERROR [2017-01-24 02:13:43,456] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:118) - Error while running jettyServer
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/zeppelin/2.5.3.0-37/0/null (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:871)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:116)
```

I have no idea what file it's trying to look for in /etc/zeppelin/2.5.3.0-37/0/

The zeppelin.ssl.keystore.path is set to conf/keystore and the keystore file is at that location.  It's a relative path under /usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server, and the conf dir there is actually a symlink to /etc/zeppelin/2.5.3.0-37/0/

I have client auth set to false, but set the truststore path nonetheless, and that didn't seem to make any difference.

If I toggle the zeppelin.ssl setting to "false" the server starts normally.

Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK, in Ambari the tooltip for the keystore path field says it should be a relative path, relative to zeppelin home.  But just now on a whim I changed it to the absolute path, and now my server starts in SSL mode.  I don't know if the docs are wrong, or if it's a code bug, but it works with an absolute path, so at least I have a path forward.